# Stop for from indexing too much

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have to decode an input of numerals. Each number from 1-26 corresponds to A-Z, for example 1-A, 2-B,...26-Z. I made a dictionary which covers this.
My output needs to be a text made from decoding the numbers.

For instance my input can be: `195318520`

`19` is in my dictionary as `S`, next I'll take `53` which is not, so I print the letter `E` from `5`, then `31`, the same it's not so I print `C`, next `18` which is `R`, and so on until I get `SECRET`. `"00"` will be `" "` in the text and `"01"` will be `"1"`...`"09"` - `"9"`.

So I made this code, which I know it's kind of butchered but somehow it's printing the right thing but I get and error at the end.

```
from textwrap import wrap
import sys
sir=raw_input().strip('')

d= {"00":" ",'1':'A', '2':'B', '3':'C' , '4':'D' , '5':'E', '6':'F', '7':'G', '8':'H', '9':'I', "10":'J', "11":'K', "12":'L', "13":'M', "14":'N', "15":'O', "16":'P',"17":'Q', "18":'R', "19":'S', "20":'T', "21":'U', "22":'V',"23":'W', "24":'X', "25":'Y', "26":'Z' }

pair=wrap(sir,1)

d["01"]=d["1"]
d["02"]=d["2"]
d["03"]=d["3"]
d["04"]=d["4"]
d["05"]=d["5"]
d["06"]=d["6"]
d["07"]=d["7"]
d["08"]=d["8"]
d["09"]=d["9"]

for i in range(len(pair)):
    pair[i:i+2]=[''.join(pair[i:i+2])]
    pair[i]=pair[i].strip()
    if pair[i] <= "26":
        sys.stdout.write(d[pair[i]])
        #print d[pair[i]] 
    else:
        pair[i]=list(pair[i])
        sys.stdout.write(d[pair[i][0]])
        #print d[pair[i][0]] 
        pair.insert(i+1,pair[i][1])
```

Input: 195318520

`SECRETTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "decodare.py", line 27, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write(d[pair[i]])
KeyError: ''`

I think the problem is `for` its indexing too much, `len(pair)` has a fix value but my `i` it's rather dynamic and depends on the pair of numerals taken.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what benefit you get from `textwrap`, but this function works with your sample input:

```
def parse(sir):
    ret = []
    taken = False
    for index,n in enumerate(sir):
        if not taken:
            dbl = (''.join(sir[index:]) + '0')[:2]
            val = int(dbl)
            taken = True
            if 1 <= val <= 26:
                ret.append(chr(val + 64))
            elif val == 0:
                ret.append(' ')
            else:
                taken = False
                val = int(n)
                ret.append(chr(val + 64))
        else:
            taken = False


    return ''.join(ret)

sir = '195318520'

print(parse(sir))
```

Output:

```
SECRET
```

Comment: I have no doubt this will work, but i want to repair my code if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, keeping with the use of `wrap` and your `dict`:

```
d= {"00":" ",'1':'A', '2':'B', '3':'C' , '4':'D' , '5':'E', '6':'F', '7':'G', '8':'H', '9':'I', "10":'J', "11":'K', "12":'L', "13":'M', "14":'N', "15":'O', "16":'P',"17":'Q', "18":'R', "19":'S', "20":'T', "21":'U', "22":'V',"23":'W', "24":'X', "25":'Y', "26":'Z' }

d["01"]=d["1"]
d["02"]=d["2"]
d["03"]=d["3"]
d["04"]=d["4"]
d["05"]=d["5"]
d["06"]=d["6"]
d["07"]=d["7"]
d["08"]=d["8"]
d["09"]=d["9"]

def parse(sir):
    ret = []
    taken = False
    for index,n in enumerate(sir):
        if not taken:
            dbl = (''.join(sir[index:]) + '0')[:2]
            val = int(dbl)
            taken = True
            if 0 <= val <= 26:
                ret.append(d[dbl])
            else:
                taken = False
                val = int(n)
                ret.append(d[n])
        else:
            taken = False


    return ''.join(ret)

sir = '195318520'
pair=wrap(sir, 1)

print(parse(pair))
```

Output:

```
SECRET
```

Comment: U didnt understand me. tho i appreciate the effort, I dont want to implement another function. I think some adjusment to the `for` syntax in my code will do the trick. I asked if u can tell me how to repair my code.

Comment: Oh, I think I did, but I'm not going to go there. My estimate was that by the time I'd made all the corrections it would end up at one of the two answers I've posted.